# PHP include seems to make page interpret itself as a directory

Tags: php, include, document-root

I have a page, `index.php`, like this (simplified):

```
<img src="content/banner.png"/>
```

The image loads fine. But when I include a certain (WordPress) script, like so,

```
<img src="content/banner.png"/>
<?php
    include('template-loader.php');
?>
```

the image no longer loads! I also notice the URL in the browser becomes `index.php/`.

How is this possible? The image of course won't load because I'm using relative paths and it's looking for `index.php/content/banner.jpg`. True, I can use absolute paths to fix this issue, but I'd like to know what could be happening and how the problem might be fixed in PHP.

I'm testing on a local `wamp` installation and have disabled all `mod_rewrite`s and such, to be sure it's not something external causing the problem.

Comment: Does it happen if you do: `include(dirname(__FILE__).'template-loader.php');`

Comment: @Cthulhu - I actually tried that, and variants using WordPress's `ABSPATH` as well but to no avail. I just found the actual culprit and answered my own question. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh. Minutes after posting, I found the culprit, right in the script:

```
/**
 * Loads the correct template based on the visitor's url
 * @package WordPress
 */
if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
        do_action('template_redirect');
```

It's doing some kind of a redirect; commenting this out makes everything work as expected.

I still don't really understand how this script can magically redirect to `index.php/` as if it were a directory (and have the document actually load) but...

*I will delete this question in the future if it doesn't seem to be helping anyone (based on views and votes).*